# How can I specify which protocol to use (IPv4 or IPv6) when pinging a website (bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I currently have a shell script which simply takes a URL as an argument and then sends a ping request to it as follows:

```
ping -c 5 $1
```

It is required of me to ping to the site using IPv4 and IPv6 where possible, I will then compare results. I have read the man page of ping and cannot see a flag which specifies which protocol to use, I was expecting it to accept a flag -4 for IPv4 and -6 for IPv6 but this does not seem to be the case.

I came across the DNS lookup utility `dig` which looks promising but have not managed to implement it in my code. My script must take a URL as an argument and no other arguments. I hope this is clear and thanks for your help.

Comment: My `ping` understands `-4` and `-6`, Arch Linux and Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: You should also have `ping6`

Comment: Thanks Paul I was not aware of this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ping` and `ping6` that are available in most distributions.

```
/tmp $ dig google.com A google.com AAAA +short
172.217.4.174
2607:f8b0:4007:801::200e

/tmp $ ping -c 2 172.217.4.174
PING 172.217.4.174 (172.217.4.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=35.619 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.4.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=34.220 ms

/tmp $ ping6 -c 2 2607:f8b0:4007:801::200e
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2602:306:b826:68a0:f40e:abca:efdb:71f --> 2607:f8b0:4007:801::200e
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4007:801::200e, icmp_seq=0 hlim=55 time=77.735 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4007:801::200e, icmp_seq=1 hlim=55 time=81.518 ms
```

Comment: Thanks helloV for bringing ping6 to my attention, I will accept your answer once stack overflow lets me